In Drupal, how do I call a custom serializer from a _node_update hook?
We inherited a legacy Drupal project that has an entity called Products. We expose an API endpoint that returns all Products as JSON.
Our project uses a module that contains a custom serializer:
// modules\custom\my_module\src\Plugin\views\style\CustomizedSerializer.php

class CustomizedSerializer extends Serializer {
  function render($unserialized) {
    \Drupal::logger('php')->notice('CustomizedSerializer::render');
    // ...
  }
}

We know this custom serializer is used for Products because after viewing the JSON API endpoint for Products the above log statement in render shows up in our logs.
When a Product is edited through the admin portal, we want to dump all the Products' data into a static JSON file, using the CustomizedSerializer to generate the JSON. Here's our attempt:
// modules\custom\my_module\my_module.module

function my_module_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'product') {
    $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', 'product')->execute();
    $nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
    $serializer = \Drupal::service('serializer');
    $result = $serializer->serialize($nodes, 'json');
    $file = fopen('sites/default/files/products.json', 'w');
    fwrite($file, $result);
    fclose($file);
  }
}

However, \Drupal::service('serializer') appears to call a serializer other than the CustomizedSerializer since the above log statement doesn't appear, and the output is different from the output of the JSON API endpoint.
How can we call the CustomizedSerializer?

If the parent class has no constructor, then you can just call $x = new CustomizedSerializer(). (obviously use statement for namespace too)

looks like it uses symfony serializer under the hood, so you might need to pass in normalizers and encoders https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#usage

The serializer has a public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition), so we figured it needed to be instantiated with some parameters, and hoped that it would already have been instantiated and usable. Is that incorrect?

i dont use drupal, but i'll guess there is some sort of service config key? in this case you'd need to define yours as something different, ie customized_serializer

@delboy1978uk Unfortunately it wasn't that simple. :)
